# Using Python to Download CVS "Download CSV" Button

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to download the csv file using Python from this site:https://gats.pjm-eis.com/gats2/PublicReports/GATSGenerators

There's a csv button in the top right corner that I want to automatically load into a data warehouse. I've gone through a few tutorials (new to Python) and have yet to be successful. Any recommendations?

Comment: Looks like you'll need to use something like Selenium to automate a browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the library called requests, it is:

```
import requests
```

You need it to create the request to the cvs resource.

Also there's a library used for **screen-scraping** called bs4

```
import bs4
```

You will need both to construct what you want. Look for a course over there on web scraping with python and bs4.

Also there's a library called csv,

```
import csv
```

You can use it to easily parse the csv file once you get it.

Check this example or google it:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-scrape-web-pages-with-beautiful-soup-and-python-3

Here's another course on LinkedIn learning platform

https://www.linkedin.com/learning/scripting-for-testers/welcome

Comment: Just a detail: bs4 is not meant for web scraping but rather can be used for *parsing* HTML code of scraped websites.

Comment: By the way, on the Anaconda libraries installer it says: "Python library designed for screen-scraping". So, I'm guessing that's the correct term.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium did the trick for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
url = 'https://gats.pjm-eis.com/gats2/PublicReports/GATSGenerators'
browser.get(url) 

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="CSV"]').click()
browser.close()
```